# AFNetworking: Do I need to delete downloaded file myself?

Tags: ios, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, afnetworking-3

I'm using AFNetworking to download a zip file. Upon completion this block is called.

```
- (void)setDownloadTaskDidFinishDownloadingBlock:(nullable NSURL * _Nullable  (^)(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask, NSURL *location))block;
```

When the download completes, I simply extract the contents to my desired location.

```
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:location toDestination:unzipPath];
```

Theres two questions I have about this.

1) Do I need to delete the original file at the NSURL location myself? Or will the system do this automatically?

2) What exactly am I supposed to return in this block?

Edit:
Looking at the code, it looks like I can return nil in that block and AFNetworking will not move the file. But should I delete the original file at *location*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> 1. Do I need to delete the original file at the `NSURL` location myself? Or will the system do this automatically?

The system will do that for you.

> 2. What exactly am I supposed to return in this block?

The standard behavior is that you would return the `NSURL` for the local location (e.g. in the Documents or Cache folder), and, if so, AFNetworking will move it to there for you when the download is done.

Comment: In regards to #2 is there any reason not to go against the standard? I need to extract files, scan the directory, delete unnecessary stuff, etc.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can just unzip it directly in `setDownloadTaskDidFinishDownloadingBlock` rather than just returning the URL to where it should be moved, and then let `setTaskDidCompleteBlock` initiate the unzipping process? While the AFNetworking documentation doesn't contemplate this, the `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` docs do. Having said that, the `NSURLSession` docs are ambiguous about when exactly that file will be removed, and given that you probably want to unzip on a separate thread, I'd be inclined to follow the standard pattern.

Comment: Here's an example of what I'm doing https://gist.github.com/Hackmodford/abeae16b00cc3cf2b11c